# How to extract data from content of files, including a string and ignoring new line

Tags: bash, grep

I want to retrieve service names from a project whole directory.

All service calls start with specific pattern:

```
getService().serviceName1()
getService().service2()

getService().
thirdSName()
```

Notice how the last match above is folded over two lines; the first line matches the pattern but the service name is wrapped onto the following line.

My solution:

```
grep -r  "getService" *
```

Expected report:

```
serviceName1
service2
thirdSName
```

But my `grep` results are incomplete because they don't include the last service name.

Comment: You can try: `grep -r "Service()" *`

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan Thanks, but service name can be anything. the only fixed string is "getService"

Comment: Can you please post your expected output?

Comment: `grep -E -r '\w+Service' *`

Comment: `thirdServiceName` does not match your fixed string, and of course neither does it match the regex either then.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks. Yes because there is an extra enter. I want to ignore it

Comment: Use recursive grep with . and not with *, or you'll skip all hidden files and directories

Answer (score 0):

`grep` can't easily choose how much to show of a match if it stretches across multiple lines; there is only a facility for specifying a fixed number of context lines before or after the match.

If your needs are pedestrian, maybe try something like this simple Awk script.

```sh
find . -type f -exec awk '/getService/ || more {
    print FILENAME ":" NR ":" $0; more = ($0 ~ /\.[ \t]*$/) }' {} +
```

This simply checks whether the last non-whitespace character is a dot, and if so, selects the following line(s) for printing as well.

If your requirements are less modest, a parser for the programming language used in these files is probably the way to go. If your requirements are only marginally less modest, maybe the Awk approach can be stretched for a tiny little bit more.

(The `find` wrapper is because Awk doesn't have a `-r` option for traversing a directory tree.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is find command combined with a python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

pyscript="$(cat <<'EOF'
import re,sys
print( 
    *re.findall(                         # Find all the occurrences
        r'(?:getService\(\)\.\s*)(\w+)', # regex with non-capturing group
        open(sys.argv[1]).read(),        # Open and read whole file
        re.DOTALL), # Make the '.' special character match any character at all
    sep="\n"        # print with element on its own line.
)
EOF 
)" 

find . -type f -exec python -c "$pyscript" {} \;
```